# Why does this for loop not detect if the word entered by a user is sorted alphabetically?

Tags: python, for-loop, input

I am trying to write a program such that it accepts a word as input and determine if its letters are in alphabetical order.

My code:

```
words = str(input("Enter a word")) #Coal
for i in words:
    if not sorted:
        print("Letters not in alphabetical order")
    else:
        print("Letters are in alphabetical order")
```

However, the output I am receiving even for #coal which is not sorted is coming as "letters are in alphabetical order". What is wrong with my code and syntax?

Comment: This isn't how `sorted` works. It's a function that you need to call: `sorted(words)`.

Comment: What is `sorted`?

Comment: It is a method which returns an iterable from a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
if not sorted:
```

Doesn't actually check anything. `sorted` is a built-in function that is truthy, so `not sorted` is always `False`. To use `sorted`, you have to give it an argument.

Iterating the string is not needed. You should also set the string to lowercase:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ").lower()
if word != ''.join(sorted(word)):
    print("Letters not in alphabetical order")
else:
    print("Letters are in alphabetical order")
```

Comment: Thank you Timothy. I am new to python, could you please tell me how join is used here and explain line 2 in that context

Comment: @JoeyTribhuvan It means "if the original word is not equal to the sorted word converted into a string:".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
words = str(input("Enter a word")) #Coal
for word in words:
  if word !=''.join(sorted(word)):
    print("Letters not in alphabetical order")
else:
    print("Letters are in alphabetical order")
```